# If 40.0 grams of Aluminum and 25.0 gram of Cl2 reacted together how much AlCl3 can be produced?

Tags: stoichiometry

The equation goes as follows: Al + Cl2 ----> AlCl3.
The equation is unbalanced so I then balanced the equation.

Heres what I did: 2Al + 3Cl2 ---> 2AlCl3

I then got the Molar mass of 40 g of Aluminum.

40.0g * (1 mol Al/ 26.98)= 1.49 mol Al

I did the same for 25g of Cl2

25.0g * (1 mol Cl2/ 70.9)= .35 mol Cl2

I am unsure as to what to do next. Do I simply multiply the two masses and then times them by two because of the 2AlCl3. I'm struggling with stoichiometry. Next on the list would be identifying the limiting and excess reagents and the % yield. This is my first crack at it.

Answer (score 1):

First, $40$ g of $Al$ is $1.482$ mol $Al$. And $25$ g $Cl_2$ is $0.352$ mol $Cl_2$. You should see that there is too much aluminum. $0.35$ mol $Cl_2$ reacts with $(2/3)·0.352$ mol $Al$ = $0.2347$ mol $Al$. This is less than 
$1.428$ mol.

As you want to obtain the mass of $AlCl_3$, you must see that the number of moles of $AlCl_3$ is the same as the amount of the used aluminum, i.e. $0.2347$ mol.
And $0.2347$ mole of $AlCl_3$ weighs $0.2347·133.33$ g = $31.29$ g. This is the theoretical yield.